# Replace decimals 1 to 10 with name ("one", "two"..)

Tags: java, regex, string

I was trying to take a string and then returns a string with the numbers 1 to 10 replaced with the word for those numbers. For example:

> I won 7 of the 10 games and received 30 dollars.

should become:

> I won **seven** of the **ten** games and received 30 dollars.

So I did this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

String[] numbers = new String[] {"1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
String[] words   = new String[]{"one", "two", "three","four","five","six",
    "seven","eight","nine","ten"};
System.out.print(StringUtils.replaceEach(phrase, numbers, words));
```

And the result is this:

> I won seven of the one0 games and received three0 dollars.

So I tried a brute force way which I'm sure could be improved with regular expressions or more elegant string manipulation:

```
public class StringReplace {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String phrase = "I won 7 of the 10 games and received 30 dollars.";
    String[] sentenceWords = phrase.split(" ");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s: sentenceWords) { 
      if (isNumeric(s)) { 
        sb.append(switchOutText(s));
      }

      else { 
        sb.append(s);
      }
      sb.append(" ");

    }
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
  }

  public static String switchOutText(String s) { 
    if (s.equals("1"))
      return "one";
    else if (s.equals("2"))
      return "two";
    else if (s.equals("3"))
      return "three";
    else if (s.equals("4"))
      return "four";
    else if (s.equals("5"))
      return "fivee";
    else if (s.equals("6"))
      return "six";
    else if (s.equals("7"))
      return "seven";
    else if (s.equals("8"))
      return "eight";
    else if (s.equals("9"))
      return "nine";        
    else if (s.equals("10"))
      return "ten";
    else
      return s;        
  }

  public static boolean isNumeric(String s) { 
    try { 
      int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { 
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Isn't there a better way?  Especially interested in regex suggestions.

Comment: This seems like a pretty straightforward call to String.replaceAll() would suffice. Just make sure to start with 10 to avoid the problem of "one0".

Comment: You could try moving `10` to the front of the array, so that it will get evaluated before `1`. But there's probably a more proper change.

Comment: @KevinWorkman The OP also needs to handle avoiding the "3" in "30" getting replaced with "three".

Comment: @GriffeyDog Good catch. BobbyD17's answer below seems like a good solution.

Comment: I dont think that this is possible with a single RegExp since there is no way to pass a mappingtable to a RegExp - as far as I know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This approach uses regular expressions to match the target digit surrounded by non-digits (or the start or end character):

```
String[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
    "eight", "nine", "ten" };
String phrase = "I won 7 of the 10 games and received 30 dollars.";

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  String pattern = "(^|\\D)" + i + "(\\D|$)";
  phrase = phrase.replaceAll(pattern, "$1" + words[i - 1] + "$2");
}

System.out.println(phrase);
```

This prints:

> I won seven of the ten games and received 30 dollars.

It also copes if the number is the first or last word in the sentence. For instance:

> 9 cats turned on 100 others and killed 10

correctly translates to

> nine cats turned on 100 others and killed ten

Comment: Does it cover this case: My favorite number is 7, but I also like 5.

Comment: @BobbyD17 A quick test suggests yes. What made you suspect it might not?

Comment: It was one of the comments brought up under my answer. I was just making sure that you checked for it. I have never used the pattern like you did, and I wasn't quite sure how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Before replacing any number with a word, you need to check that the number is not followed or preceeded by another number. This is probably the only way to be sure that it is not part of a bigger number. So you won't be replacing "30" with "three0" and so on. This will allow it to be "30 " or "30." or "30," or any other punctuation mark. So, the check will have to make sure it is not 0-9.

Comment: You would also need to handle the case where the number is followed by a period and not a space.

Comment: good point. Maybe you will have to first check that each phrase is not followed by a number. So before you replace anything make sure the next character is not a number. Adding this as an edit.

Comment: For HTML this might be working because spaces are collapsed. In any other cases this is a poor solution.

Comment: it would also need to check that the previous character is not a number, otherwise "31" will become "3one"

Comment: Thanks for the corrections to this case. I made the changes. Let me know if this is a sound solution to this problem?

Comment: This answer is more like a comment, now. It just advises of one area of caution when approaching a solution - it doesn't actually provide an answer.

Comment: @Duncan That's not true. IT may not have written code, but it provides an answer for how to solve the problem, and it does it in a way that can be used by people that don't know java as well. It also shows people who may be new to coding how to think about this problem rather than just giving them an answer. If you don't want to up vote my answer that's fine, I just want to make sure that anyone that finds this post in a google search can get what they need out of it.